# How to do the equivalent of a <script> when testing an Angular component with Karma?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dependencies, karma-runner

I am writing a component who needs external scripts to work. Currently the scripts are injected though our index.html like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      window.myExternalLibraryConfigurationObject = {
        // some keys-values here
      };
    </script>

    <script src="https://my-internal-repository.com/widgets/my-external-library/my-widget.js"></script>
  </head>
  <!-- Body -->
</html>
```

How can I do the same things when testing an Angular component with Karma ? I believe I can inject the external library by adding this line in my `karma.conf.js` but for setting up the configuration object I don't know:

```
files: [
  'https://my-internal-repository.com/widgets/my-external-library/my-widget.js'
]
```

Thanks in advance,
Thomas